# How can Cancan ability handle two user models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I working permision with cancan gem.

How can I get "CANCAN" to manage permission for two models?

thanks

==================================

I can do this ????

```
class Ability

  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
   # code
  end

  def initialize(accounts)
     #code  
  end
end
```

Comment: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/changing-defaults

Comment: You mean two different type of users? Are both responding to current_user? Or just two abilities, based in something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify what models certain users can manipulate and perform actions on in your ability.rb file.

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  # usual setup
  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new

    if user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    end

    if user.has_role? :less_important_role
      can [:read, :update], Model1
      can :manage, Model2
    end
  end
end
```

Checkout the [docs](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities) to read more about defining abilities.

Comment: Per Example I nedd ability to User model and Account models, what is the best way to solved this.   

 def initialize(user)
 def initialize(accounts) ???? 

Thanks !!!

Comment: CanCan was not made to support [two different models](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/cantango/wiki/CanCan-vs-CanTango) at the same time but it can support different types of single model. If you really need to setup permissions for two separate models then you should checkout [CanTango](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/cantango) which extends many of the functionalities of CanCan. Im not familiar with it but might be worth a look. Also, consider if you really need to monitor Account models with a full set of roles or if just a method or two within the Account model would suffice.

Answer (score 4):

```
class ApplicationHelper
  def current_auth_resource
    if admin_signed_in?
      current_admin
    else
      current_user
    end
  end

  def current_ability
      @current_ability or @current_ability = Ability.new(current_auth_resource)
  end
end

class ApplicationController
  include ApplicationHelper
end

class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)      
    if user.is_a?(Admin)
      # add admin permissions only
    elsif user.is_a?(User)
      # add user permissions only
    else
      # add guest permissions only
    end
  end
end
```

check [this](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/656)